# access list with list of indices

Tags: python, list

I want to create a new list from 2 lists.

One list (self.sequence) contains the desired indexes generated by input from QlineEdit(). E.g. when I type 0,1,2,6:11,0,23 in the QlineEdit, the outputted list looks like this (input is automatically converted to unicode):

```
[u'0', u'1', u'2', u'6:11', u'0', u'23']
```

The other list (xcoord) is just a regular list of values.

The newly created list should contain the values from list (self.sequence) but only at the indexes from list (coord).
This is my code. right now gives a TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

```
    self.sequence_input = QtGui.QLineEdit()    

def on_adjust(self):
    self.sequence = self.sequence_input.text().split(',')
    print self.sequence
    self.xseq = self.xcoord[self.sequence]
    self.yseq = self.ycoord[self.sequence]
    print self.xse
```

I have been looking at similar questions before but I couldn't apply the answers to my case. I am fairly new to python.

Comment: self.xcoord is that a function or a variable? If its a variable then that's the problem.

Comment: self.coord is a list. I know you can't access a list like that but I thought I'd just show what I have right now

Comment: I tried square brackets, also didn't work

Comment: `print self.sequence` what did it print i think it is a list

Comment: and is `self.xseq` a list which has the value of  `self.xcoord[self.sequence]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### List index needs to be an int

The value of `self.sequence` being e.g. `[u'0', u'1', u'2', u'0', u'23']` (omitted the slice here, more on that below) means it's a list of unicode strings, to use a value from there as a list index you'll have to convert the values to an `int` e.g.

```
int_sequeneces = [int(x) for x in self.sequence]
```

Now each element in `int_sequences` is an int that can be used to index a list

e.g.

```
first_index = int_sequences[0]
self.xcoord[first_index]
```

### "Access a list with a list", a simple list comprehension will do

So to get all the sequences from `xcoord` and `ycoord` you can do:

```
self.xseq = [self.xcoord[index] for index in int_sequences]
self.yseq = [self.ycoord[index] for index in int_sequences]
```

### Expanding slices

```
def expand_slice(x):
    """ 
    Converts '6:11' to [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    """
    a, b = x.split(':')
    return list(xrange(int(a), int(b)))

def parse_seq(x):
    """
    Deals with both int and slices in a uniform way,
    by returning a list of indices
    """
    return expand_slice(x) if ':' in x else [int(x)]
```

### Flattening

For the list to be used as a list of indices it'll need to be flat, where every element is a valid index e.g. an int, as in `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` as opposed to `[1, [2, 3, 4], 5]`. We can use code below to flatten it with `itertools.chain()`

```
itertools.chain(*[parse_seq(x) for x in index_and_slices])
```

This behaves like a list but you can convert it explicitly for display with `list()`

### Putting it all together

```
In [28]: import itertools

In [29]: def expand_slice(x): a, b = x.split(':'); return list(xrange(int(a), int(b)))

In [30]: def parse_seq(x): return expand_slice(x) if ':' in x else [int(x)]

In [31]: index_and_slices = [u'0', u'1', u'2', u'6:11', u'0', u'23']

In [32]: [parse_seq(x) for x in index_and_slices]
Out[33]: [[0], [1], [2], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [0], [23]]

In [32]: list(itertools.chain(*[parse_seq(x) for x in index_and_slices]))
Out[32]: [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 23]
```

### N.B.

- If for you a `6:11` means `[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]`, simply modify the `expand_slice()` function accordingly, e.g. with `xrange(int(a), int(b) + 1)`, but the behavior I put here is the default in Python tradition
- I'm not doing validation on your input but you can catch exceptions as they come and report them back to the interface (In Python often it's more elegant to ask for forgiveness than to ask for permission)

Comment: I just noticed. It will give ValueError: invalid literal for int(). Good effort though

Answer (score 0):

#### Convert your list of strings (with slices) to regular indexers for python lists

You cannot index or slice a list with a string. You have to parse your input from unicode to int. The problem is that you also have slice `6:11`. 
A solution could be something like this:

```
self.sequence = self.sequence_input.text().split(',')
print self.sequence
for obj in self.sequence.split(':'):
    to_add = obj[0] if len(obj) < 2 else slice(obj[0], obj[1])
    self.xseq.append(self.xcoord[to_add])
    self.yseq.append(self.ycoord[to_add])
```

#### Flatten the final lists

Now you may have a list of list because a slice returns a list. You can then flatten both of `self.xseq` and `self.yseq`.

```
import itertools

self.xseq = itertools.chain(*self.xseq)
self.yseq = itertools.chain(*self.yseq)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access list by providing it's index that is the position of the data you want to take and not a list:

```
for a in sel.sequence:
    if ":" in s:
        s=s.split(":")
        for ss in range(int(s[0]),int(s[1])):
            self.xseq.append(self.xcoord[ss])
    else:
        self.yseq.append(self.ycoord[int(s)])
```

**i.e.)**

```
a=["1","2","3"]

b=[2,4,5,7]

b[a]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-9f1bfc533672> in <module>()
----> 1 b[a]

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

One of the way to access would be to loop through the list:

```
a=["1","2:3","3"]

b=[2,4,5,7]
for s in a:
    if ":" in s:
        s=s.split(":")
        for ss in range(int(s[0]),int(s[1])+1):
            print b[ss]
    else:
        print b[int(s)]

4
5
7
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different kind of approach you could take:

```
xcoord = [1,5,10,15,5,3,5,20,80,70,1,5,10,15,5,3,5,20,80,70,1,5,10,15,5,3,5,20,80,70]
ycoord = [0,2,7,3,8,50,4,6,3,0,2,7,3,8,50,4,6,3,0,2,7,3,8,50,4,6,3,0]
sequences = [u'0', u'1', u'2', u'6:11', u'0', u'23']

xseq = []
yseq = []

for sequence in sequences:
    try:
        exec("xseq.append(xcoord[%s])" % sequence)
        exec("yseq.append(ycoord[%s])" % sequence)
    except IndexError:
        print "Slice sequence %s is out of range" % sequence
        break

print xseq
print yseq
```

Which gives the following output for my sample data:

```
[1, 5, 10, [5, 20, 80, 70, 1], 1, 15]
[0, 2, 7, [4, 6, 3, 0, 2], 0, 50]
```

Note, you would need to ensure your sequences were sanitised to only contain slices.